# google-authenticator QR code is clipped at the top in PuTTY

Tags: ssh, putty, google-authenticator

I use PuTTY on Windows to establish an SSH connection to a remote server and am trying to set up `google-authenticator` two-factor authentication, so I installed it on the remote server and run it to set up the QR code with an app on my phone, however the URL, which should appear right above the QR code, and QR code are clipped, rendering it invalid.

Why does this happen when using PuTTY?

- When I try scrolling up in PuTTY, I can't see the whole QR code: [image: Screenshot1]
- Not reproducible within a Linux terminal: [image: Screenshot2]

**Update**

I took a look at the Putty Settings: Terminal and Window sections but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be seeing there. I have 500 Lines of scrollback. I would have thought that would let me scroll up the screen to see all the QR code.

As requested here is the registry key for the OSMC profile I was using to make that ssh connection in Putty. I redacted anything private.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\OSMC]
"Present"=dword:00000001
"HostName"="192.168.1.3"
"LogFileName"="putty.log"
"LogType"=dword:00000000
"LogFileClash"=dword:ffffffff
"LogFlush"=dword:00000001
"SSHLogOmitPasswords"=dword:00000001
"SSHLogOmitData"=dword:00000000
"Protocol"="ssh"
"PortNumber"=dword:00000016
"CloseOnExit"=dword:00000001
"WarnOnClose"=dword:00000001
"PingInterval"=dword:00000000
"PingIntervalSecs"=dword:00000000
"TCPNoDelay"=dword:00000001
"TCPKeepalives"=dword:00000000
"TerminalType"="xterm"
"TerminalSpeed"="38400,38400"
"TerminalModes"="CS7=A,CS8=A,DISCARD=A,DSUSP=A,ECHO=A,ECHOCTL=A,ECHOE=A,ECHOK=A,ECHOKE=A,ECHONL=A,EOF=A,EOL=A,EOL2=A,ERASE=A,FLUSH=A,ICANON=A,ICRNL=A,IEXTEN=A,IGNCR=A,IGNPAR=A,IMAXBEL=A,INLCR=A,INPCK=A,INTR=A,ISIG=A,ISTRIP=A,IUCLC=A,IUTF8=A,IXANY=A,IXOFF=A,IXON=A,KILL=A,LNEXT=A,NOFLSH=A,OCRNL=A,OLCUC=A,ONLCR=A,ONLRET=A,ONOCR=A,OPOST=A,PARENB=A,PARMRK=A,PARODD=A,PENDIN=A,QUIT=A,REPRINT=A,START=A,STATUS=A,STOP=A,SUSP=A,SWTCH=A,TOSTOP=A,WERASE=A,XCASE=A"
"AddressFamily"=dword:00000000
"ProxyExcludeList"=""
"ProxyDNS"=dword:00000001
"ProxyLocalhost"=dword:00000000
"ProxyMethod"=dword:00000000
"ProxyHost"="proxy"
"ProxyPort"=dword:00000050
"ProxyUsername"=""
"ProxyPassword"=""
"ProxyTelnetCommand"="connect %host %port\\n"
"Environment"=""
"UserName"="osmc"
"UserNameFromEnvironment"=dword:00000000
"LocalUserName"=""
"NoPTY"=dword:00000000
"Compression"=dword:00000000
"TryAgent"=dword:00000001
"AgentFwd"=dword:00000000
"GssapiFwd"=dword:00000000
"ChangeUsername"=dword:00000000
"Cipher"="aes,chacha20,blowfish,3des,WARN,arcfour,des"
"KEX"="ecdh,dh-gex-sha1,dh-group14-sha1,rsa,WARN,dh-group1-sha1"
"RekeyTime"=dword:0000003c
"RekeyBytes"="1G"
"SshNoAuth"=dword:00000000
"SshBanner"=dword:00000001
"AuthTIS"=dword:00000000
"AuthKI"=dword:00000001
"AuthGSSAPI"=dword:00000001
"GSSLibs"="gssapi32,sspi,custom"
"GSSCustom"=""
"SshNoShell"=dword:00000000
"SshProt"=dword:00000003
"LogHost"=""
"SSH2DES"=dword:00000000
"PublicKeyFile"="anonymized"
"RemoteCommand"=""
"RFCEnviron"=dword:00000000
"PassiveTelnet"=dword:00000000
"BackspaceIsDelete"=dword:00000001
"RXVTHomeEnd"=dword:00000000
"LinuxFunctionKeys"=dword:00000000
"NoApplicationKeys"=dword:00000000
"NoApplicationCursors"=dword:00000000
"NoMouseReporting"=dword:00000000
"NoRemoteResize"=dword:00000000
"NoAltScreen"=dword:00000000
"NoRemoteWinTitle"=dword:00000000
"RemoteQTitleAction"=dword:00000001
"NoDBackspace"=dword:00000000
"NoRemoteCharset"=dword:00000000
"ApplicationCursorKeys"=dword:00000000
"ApplicationKeypad"=dword:00000000
"NetHackKeypad"=dword:00000000
"AltF4"=dword:00000001
"AltSpace"=dword:00000000
"AltOnly"=dword:00000000
"ComposeKey"=dword:00000000
"CtrlAltKeys"=dword:00000001
"TelnetKey"=dword:00000000
"TelnetRet"=dword:00000001
"LocalEcho"=dword:00000002
"LocalEdit"=dword:00000002
"Answerback"="PuTTY"
"AlwaysOnTop"=dword:00000000
"FullScreenOnAltEnter"=dword:00000000
"HideMousePtr"=dword:00000000
"SunkenEdge"=dword:00000000
"WindowBorder"=dword:00000001
"CurType"=dword:00000000
"BlinkCur"=dword:00000000
"Beep"=dword:00000000
"BeepInd"=dword:00000000
"BellWaveFile"=""
"BellOverload"=dword:00000001
"BellOverloadN"=dword:00000005
"BellOverloadT"=dword:000007d0
"BellOverloadS"=dword:00001388
"ScrollbackLines"=dword:000001f4
"DECOriginMode"=dword:00000000
"AutoWrapMode"=dword:00000001
"LFImpliesCR"=dword:00000000
"CRImpliesLF"=dword:00000000
"DisableArabicShaping"=dword:00000000
"DisableBidi"=dword:00000000
"WinNameAlways"=dword:00000001
"WinTitle"=""
"TermWidth"=dword:00000078
"TermHeight"=dword:00000020
"Font"="Courier New"
"FontIsBold"=dword:00000000
"FontCharSet"=dword:00000000
"FontHeight"=dword:0000000c
"FontQuality"=dword:00000000
"FontVTMode"=dword:00000004
"UseSystemColours"=dword:00000000
"TryPalette"=dword:00000000
"ANSIColour"=dword:00000001
"Xterm256Colour"=dword:00000001
"BoldAsColour"=dword:00000001
"Colour0"="187,187,187"
"Colour1"="255,255,255"
"Colour2"="0,0,0"
"Colour3"="85,85,85"
"Colour4"="0,0,0"
"Colour5"="0,255,0"
"Colour6"="0,0,0"
"Colour7"="85,85,85"
"Colour8"="187,0,0"
"Colour9"="255,85,85"
"Colour10"="0,187,0"
"Colour11"="85,255,85"
"Colour12"="187,187,0"
"Colour13"="255,255,85"
"Colour14"="0,0,187"
"Colour15"="85,85,255"
"Colour16"="187,0,187"
"Colour17"="255,85,255"
"Colour18"="0,187,187"
"Colour19"="85,255,255"
"Colour20"="187,187,187"
"Colour21"="255,255,255"
"RawCNP"=dword:00000000
"PasteRTF"=dword:00000000
"MouseIsXterm"=dword:00000000
"RectSelect"=dword:00000000
"MouseOverride"=dword:00000001
"Wordness0"="0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"
"Wordness32"="0,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1"
"Wordness64"="1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2"
"Wordness96"="1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1"
"Wordness128"="1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1"
"Wordness160"="1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1"
"Wordness192"="2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2"
"Wordness224"="2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2"
"LineCodePage"="UTF-8"
"CJKAmbigWide"=dword:00000000
"UTF8Override"=dword:00000001
"Printer"=""
"CapsLockCyr"=dword:00000000
"ScrollBar"=dword:00000001
"ScrollBarFullScreen"=dword:00000000
"ScrollOnKey"=dword:00000000
"ScrollOnDisp"=dword:00000001
"EraseToScrollback"=dword:00000001
"LockSize"=dword:00000000
"BCE"=dword:00000001
"BlinkText"=dword:00000000
"X11Forward"=dword:00000000
"X11Display"=""
"X11AuthType"=dword:00000001
"X11AuthFile"=""
"LocalPortAcceptAll"=dword:00000000
"RemotePortAcceptAll"=dword:00000000
"PortForwardings"=""
"BugIgnore1"=dword:00000000
"BugPlainPW1"=dword:00000000
"BugRSA1"=dword:00000000
"BugIgnore2"=dword:00000000
"BugHMAC2"=dword:00000000
"BugDeriveKey2"=dword:00000000
"BugRSAPad2"=dword:00000000
"BugPKSessID2"=dword:00000000
"BugRekey2"=dword:00000000
"BugMaxPkt2"=dword:00000000
"StampUtmp"=dword:00000001
"LoginShell"=dword:00000001
"ScrollbarOnLeft"=dword:00000000
"BoldFont"=""
"BoldFontIsBold"=dword:00000001
"BoldFontCharSet"=dword:02aa64a6
"BoldFontHeight"=dword:77704dcd
"WideFont"=""
"WideFontIsBold"=dword:00000001
"WideFontCharSet"=dword:0018ff78
"WideFontHeight"=dword:776c3436
"WideBoldFont"=""
"WideBoldFontIsBold"=dword:00000001
"WideBoldFontCharSet"=dword:0018faf0
"WideBoldFontHeight"=dword:01006446
"ShadowBold"=dword:00000000
"ShadowBoldOffset"=dword:00000001
"SerialLine"="COM1"
"SerialSpeed"=dword:00002580
"SerialDataBits"=dword:00000008
"SerialStopHalfbits"=dword:00000002
"SerialParity"=dword:00000000
"SerialFlowControl"=dword:00000001
"WindowClass"=""
"LogHeader"=dword:00000001
"ProxyLogToTerm"=dword:00000001
"HostKey"="ed25519,ecdsa,rsa,dsa,WARN"
"GssapiRekey"=dword:00000002
"AuthGSSAPIKEX"=dword:00000001
"NoRemoteClearScroll"=dword:00000000
"TrueColour"=dword:00000001
"UTF8linedraw"=dword:00000000
"PasteControls"=dword:00000000
"MouseAutocopy"=dword:00000001
"MousePaste"="explicit"
"CtrlShiftIns"="explicit"
"CtrlShiftCV"="none"
"BugOldGex2"=dword:00000000
"BugWinadj"=dword:00000000
"BugChanReq"=dword:00000000
"ConnectionSharing"=dword:00000000
"ConnectionSharingUpstream"=dword:00000001
"ConnectionSharingDownstream"=dword:00000001
"SSHManualHostKeys"=""
```

Thanks

Comment: This is likely due to the _Settings_ → _Terminal_ and/or _Settings_ → _Windows_ configuration. If you're unable to determine which setting, please add the output of the following registry key, within a code box, to your question: `HKCU\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\<session name>` _(where `<session name>` is the name of the saved profile - if not using a saved profile: `Default%20Settings`. Please anonymize the following DWORDs and Strings before posting: `HostName`, `PortForwardings`, `PublicKeyFile`, and `ProxyTelnetCommand`)_

Comment: I updated my question. Any help much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: If you used an OpenSSH Client instance instead of putty does it behave as you might expect?

Comment: @FlexMcMurphy Try increasing scrollback _(I use `100000`)_ and changing _Connection_ → _Data_ → _Terminal-type String_ to `xterm-256color`. If neither of those fix it, you may want to submit a [bug report](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/feedback.html), and you may also want to check the `termcap`  config on the remote server if it's using one _(e.g. `/usr/share/misc/termcap`, with the location varying by OS)_

Comment: @Ramhound I don't understand what you mean by "an OpenSSH Client instance"? I tried from a terminal on Raspbian OS and it worked. When it doesn't work in Putty I first ssh in to a Raspberry Pi then from there I use mosh to ssh to the remote server and run google-authenticate from the remote server. I guess the mosh command creates an OpenSSH Client instance?

Comment: Windows 10 has a built-in OpenSSH client.

Comment: @JW0914 I increased the scrollback in Putty and changed the Terminal-type string as you suggested and that fixed the problem thank you. Putty is way more usable now!  I don't know about termcap.. I read something about terminfo but it was confusing and in my case it seems it wasn't needed. If you want to make an answer I will accept it. Cheers.

Comment: @FlexMcMurphy You likely already made this correlation, but in case someone else with the issue does not, the reason this didn't occur when using SSH in a terminal is because terminals have their own scrollback settings that are often set quite high

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PuTTY's settings, increase the scrollback and change terminal-type to `xterm-256color`:

1. *Window* → *Lines of scrollback*: `100000`
2. *Connection* → Data → *Terminal-type String*: `xterm-256color`

If neither of these fix the issue, please check the `terminfo`/`termcap` config on the remote server for the settings configured for `xterm`, `xterm-256color`, or other terminal-type string being used.